About Shor's quantum algorithm
I know very little about quantum computing, and I've been trying to understand Shor's algorithm for the factorization of an integer $N$. I'm following Computational Complexity — a modern approach by Arara and Barak, which I find enjoyable to read.
There is a specific step in the algorithm which I don't understand, or rather, I don't understand how it can be done efficiently. It is no doubt the result of a deeper misunderstanding on my part, about quantum computing in general, and I feel that if I could wrap my head around this particular point, many other things would become clearer.
I hope the notation is self-explanatory in what follows. Integers are sometimes identified with the strings of 0's and 1's which you get by writing them in base 2.
So things are reduced to computing the multiplicative order (mod $N$) of a random $A$. At some point, we are in the step
$$ \left( \frac{1}{M} \sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}/M} \lvert x\rangle \right) \otimes \lvert0^n\rangle $$
for some appropriate $M$ and some $n$ (details don't matter). The next step is then to apply the map
$$\lvert x\rangle \otimes \lvert y\rangle \mapsto \lvert x\rangle\otimes \lvert y \oplus (A^x \bmod N)\rangle. $$
This confuses me. I know that, given a fixed $x$, we can compute $A^x$ efficiently, with $O(\log(x))$ operations. However, as I understand it we are required to do the same for all $x$ here! it's more like $\log(M!)$ operations (and $M$ is close to $N$).
Also, if we end up computing $A^x$ for all $x$, and what we want is the order of $A$, why don't we stop when we find the smallest $x$ such that $A^x=1$… obviously something else is meant here. But what?

I'm not sure I entirely follow your first issue or where your $log M!$ is coming from.  Peter Shor showed that one can use the familiar trick of modular exponentiation to build a quantum circuit that efficiently computes $|x\rangle \otimes |y \rangle \mapsto |x\rangle \otimes |y + A^x \rangle$.

As far as the issue in your last paragraph, it is important to remember that access to a quantum state that "knows" something about which $x$ satisfy $A^x =1$ does not mean that you get to see $x$ "for free."  You have to perform a measurement first, and typically will have to get lucky to learn anything useful even after doing so.  I would recommend reading Nielsen & Chuang's treatment rather than Arora & Barak, as it sounds to me like you're confused by some of the definitions involved in quantum circuits etc.

Thanks! I completely understand your second point about measuring etc. About the first point, I guess there is a circuit entirely missing from the book I'm reading (and I may drop that reference altogether, then!). I don't think i'm utterly confused about what a quantum circuit is, but in the absence of any other indication, I was assuming (for the example at hand) that you would have a first circuit for $x=1$ acting on just two qubits, then another one for $x=2$, and so on. In total, summing $\log(x)$ for all $x$ between $1$ and $M$ you do get $\log(M!)$. It appears that (to be continued)

(continued) It appears that there is one circuit that does the work "in parallel", although this word is probably wrong. At any rate, you seem to be claiming that there is a circuit doing this efficiently.

Btw the existence of this efficient circuit seem to be an absolutely major reason why the whole thing works, the rest being much less surprising, if clever. At least this is my impression at this stage.

Instead of “in parallel” you might just say “in superposition.”  I agree that the existence of this circuit is a big “quantum” ingredient that ensures Shor’s algorithm works.  Another reason is the quantum Fourier transform.  In fact, the QFT is probably not “as important.”  The modular exponentiation circuit is way more complicated and well understood to be the main bottleneck for being able to implement Shor’s algorithm fault tolerantly.

BTW, I don’t have Arora & Barak in front of me, but my memory is that their material on quantum computing is more of an overview or sketch.  I guess my point is that I can imagine them sweeping some details under the rug that could lead to this kind of confusion.

In some sense the whole algorithm might be roughly summarized by saying that (after applying some subtle classical reductions), it suffices to be able to measure the state one gets by applying modular exponentiation in superposition and then measuring in the Fourier basis.

thank you so much. If you turn this into a quick answer then I'll accept it, btw.

@Pierre Though MathOverflow is not an entirely unreasonable venue for your question, something like cs.stackexchange.com or even crypto.stackexchange.com might be more suitable, if you have further questions about quantum computing.

Per OP's suggestion, turning my comments into an answer.
It appears that there are two questions.  First, what's going on with the unitary
$$|x\rangle + |y \rangle \mapsto |x\rangle + |A^x + y \mod N\rangle$$
in Arora & Barak?  Second, why not just stop after finding the smallest $x$ with $A^x \equiv 1 \mod N$?
For the first question: I still don't have my copy of Arora & Barak handy, but my memory is that their discussion of quantum computing is rather sketchy.  One of Peter Shor's major contributions was to show that one can use the familiar trick of modular exponentiation to build a quantum circuit that efficiently computes $|x\rangle + |y \rangle \mapsto |x\rangle + |A^x + y\rangle$.  Of course, his factoring algorithm also uses the Fourier transform, but it's perhaps worth noting that the modular exponentiation circuit is more complicated and generally understood to be the main bottleneck for being able to implement Shor’s algorithm fault tolerantly.  Arora & Barak presumably does not construct this circuit and is probably just breezily asserting its existence.
The OP's second question seems to stem from Arora & Barak's sketchiness related to the first question.  In particular, one does not implement the operation $|y\rangle \mapsto |A^x + y \mod N\rangle$ for several different choices of $x$.  The key is to realize a quantum circuit for the more complicated operation of the previous paragraph, as this allows one to input a state in the first register that is in superposition over all $x \in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*$.
